Regex for a CSV matching single fields using an index
I have a simple CSV with numbers:
123,4,563,2334,32,7

I don't find a way to match only the nth position matching the numbers field by field using an index number. Is this solvable with a Regex expression?
The Regex flavour is the one used in the end for the Microsoft Regex.Match Method, but it is only passed as an arugment over a .NET API. I cannot directly program it.
The wanted output is:

123

4

563

2324

32

7


The answer from @C3roe is really a good starting point, but it matches all fields until the correct end of the wanted result. Still the beginning is on position one.
Result of ^(?:\[0-9\]+,){2}(\[0-9\]+) is 123,4,563. The desired result is 563.
So the regular expression works for the first index 0.
Result of ^(?:\[0-9\]+,){0}(\[0-9\]+) is 123. The desired result is 123.
So @Friedrich is also correct with noting the x,y problem. Hopefully I could explain the task better.

Is matching all the numbers and choosing the one you need an option?
If you know the amount of columns, then that wouldn't be a problem.

Given that .NET regex does not support \K, your current regex is probably as good as you can get.

Cannot see an answer from C3roe or Friedrich. Could you please provide them?

@DuesserBaest ^(?:[0-9]+,){2}([0-9]+) was my suggestion (made when the question was still in staging ground), https://regex101.com/r/MHxJsi/1 - the full match is everything from the start, and the first group match is actually the desired result - "standard" regex implementation behavior. But if the context in which they intend to use this, doesn't allow to access the group instead of the full match, this won't help.

Just use a CSV parser?

You can use a positive lookbehind like this:
(?<=^(?:\d+,){2})\d+

See the .NET regex demo.
Customize the {2} to get the number you want.
Details:

(?<=^(?:\d+,){2}) - a positive lookbehind that matches a position that is immediately preceded with

^ - start of string
(?:\d+,){2} - two consecutive occurrences of one or more digits followed with a comma


\d+ - one or more digits.


Thanks a lot for the solution and explanation!
